# Is there a way to create a script for google form to check a spreadsheet first?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to plan my sons 1st birthday party. I live in hawaii so when you invite someone, sometimes they tend to bring their friends, sisters, cousins, auntys, uncles, dog, etc..... but since the venue we reserved for my sons party has a limited amount of seating, we can't just have additional people come. Plus we are paying by the head/seat.

So with that said, I have a spreadsheet of my guest list and have a column for the amount of seats I have limited to each invitation. I would like to assign a code for each invitation as well.

For example
Family Name | Seats | Code Number
Family A | 3 seats | ABC123
Family B | 5 seats | DEF456

So if I place a qr code on the invitation and give each invitation/family their code,

I would like google forms to allow each recipient to enter their code and for a script to check my spreadsheet with this code they entered so the form knows how many seats the recipient is limited to reserving for.

Family A can only reserve for 3 seats and no more, and Family B can only reserve for 5 seats and no more.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't enter a code into a Google Form field and have a script function run right after.  So that kills being able to check on the validation of another field.  Only after the Form has been submitted to go the the responses can you check what the values were.

If you stick with a single Google form you could write a script that monitors submissions and sends out an email or letting them know they booked too many people (after the fact).  Could also write a script that creates a separate Form for each invite that already has the maximum guests programmed into a drop down list.  Then send each invite their own Form url.

Another way is to write your own app with one of the 2 UI Services that acts like a form.  There you can have interaction with user input and the validation you want.  Start of a UiApp example...

```
var MAX = [];
MAX['123'] = [2];
MAX['456'] = [3];

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var code = app.createTextBox().setId('code').setName('code');
  var guests = app.createTextBox().setId('guests').setName('guests');
  var submit = app.createButton('SUBMIT').setId('submit').setEnabled(false);
  var status = app.createLabel('', false).setId('status');

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('checkGuests').addCallbackElement(panel);
  guests.addValueChangeHandler(handler);

  handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
  submit.addClickHandler(handler);

  panel.add(code).add(guests).add(submit).add(status);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function checkGuests(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var code = e.parameter.code;
  var guests = e.parameter.guests;

  if (code == '' || code == undefined) { 
    app.getElementById('submit').setEnabled(false)
    app.getElementById('status').setText('Please enter your code.'); }
  else if (parseInt(guests) <= MAX[code]) {
    app.getElementById('submit').setEnabled(true);
    app.getElementById('status').setText(''); }
  else { 
    app.getElementById('submit').setEnabled(false)
    app.getElementById('status').setText('Whoops, too many people!'); }
  return app;
}

function submit(e) {
}
```